# Query simplification by using oracle sample database

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

**Task :** 
List Name and salary of highest and lowest paid employee from each department. 
You can perform the queries for highest and lowest separately also.

**Tried Query :**

```
SELECT dept.deptno, 
       dname, 
       minsal, 
       maxsal 
FROM   dept, 
       (SELECT deptno, 
               Max (sal) MAXSAL 
        FROM   emp 
        GROUP  BY deptno) MAXSALARY, 
       (SELECT deptno, 
               Min (sal)MINSAL 
        FROM   emp 
        GROUP  BY deptno) MINSALARY 
WHERE  MAXSALARY.deptno = dept.deptno 
       AND MINSALARY.deptno = dept.deptno;
```

**Result**

[image]

The Result is correct.

**Question)**
 Is there any other way to simplify the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ORACLE's window functions like `row_number` combined with conditional aggregation using `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT t.ename,t.dname,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.low_ind = 1 then t.salary END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.high_ind = 1 then t.salary END)
FROM (SELECT e.name as ename,d.name as dname,e.salary, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.name ORDER BY e.salary ASC) as low_ind,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY d.name ORDER BY e.salary DESC) as high_ind 
      FROM emp e
      INNER JOIN dept d
       ON(d.deptno = e.deptno)) t
GROUP BY t.ename,t.dname
```

**EDIT:** if all you need is the min and max salary on each department then thats a simple group by clause :

```
SELECT d.deptno,d.dname,MIN(e.salary) as min_sal,MAX(e.salary) as max_sal
FROM dept d
INNER JOIN emp e
 ON(d.deptno = e.deptno)
GROUP BY d.deptno,d.name
```

Comment: I am a beginner in sql . So can we simplify it by using simple sub-quries ? @sagi

Comment: @nafeesahmed are you required to bring back employee name? or you just need to output -> `DEPname,maxSal,minSal` ?

Comment: i NEED JUST DEPname,maxSal,minSal

Answer (score 0):

SELECT d.dname, Max(e.sal) MAXSAL, Min(e.sal) MINSAL
  FROM dept d, emp e
 WHERE d.deptno = e.deptno
 group by d.dname